# How to track a user/person in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play, google-plus

I have few apps in PlayStore. A user(fake probably) is leaving negative reviews in all of my app. I want to know his email id/or any mode of contact by which i can contact/recognise him/her. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, and if it was possible it would be a huge privacy violation for that user. You have two things you can do though:

- if the reviews are abusive, then you can flag them
- [you can reply to the review in the Play Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/engage/user-reviews). If you leave a polite reply asking them to give more detail, apologizing for any problems, and give them a way to contact you, then they might contact you. If they don't contact you, then at least anyone who sees the bad review can see that you care about customer service. Then they can guess that the review might be unfair, and your good, polite customer service might be a bigger positive than any negative effect of the review.